# Unable to start Liberty Profile from Command Line : failed to create task or type antlib:com.ibm.websphere.wlp.ant:server

Tags: ant, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

I am trying to start WebSphere Liberty profile server (named WL_UAT_Server)

```
<project basedir="." default="help" name="myProject" xmlns:wlp="antlib:com.ibm.websphere.wlp.ant">
      <target name="liberty-start">
        <wlp:server id="test" installDir="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty" operation="start" serverName="WL_UAT_Server"/>
      </target>
</project>
```

from following command:

```
ant -f /opt/myProject/build.xml "liberty-start"
```

but system is giving following error:

```
/opt/myProject/build.xml:144: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:com.ibm.websphere.wlp.ant:server
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -/usr/share/ant/lib
        -/home/root/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument


Total time: 2 seconds
```

following the the output of `ant -diagonstics` command

------- Ant diagnostics report -------
    Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on April 26 2010

```
-------------------------------------------
 Implementation Version
-------------------------------------------
core tasks     : 1.7.1
optional tasks : not available

-------------------------------------------
 ANT PROPERTIES
-------------------------------------------
ant.version: Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on April 26 2010
ant.java.version: 1.6
ant.core.lib: /usr/share/java/ant-1.7.1.jar
ant.home: /usr/share/ant

-------------------------------------------
 ANT_HOME/lib jar listing
-------------------------------------------
ant.home: /usr/share/ant
ant.jar (1339582 bytes)
ant-launcher.jar (12243 bytes)
ant-bootstrap.jar (19013 bytes)
wlp-anttasks.jar (43990 bytes)

-------------------------------------------
 USER_HOME/.ant/lib jar listing
-------------------------------------------
user.home: /root
No such directory.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running Ant as stand alone tool or from Eclipse or other dev tool?

Comment: @Gas I am running it from the command line.

Comment: Though luck :-). I thought, that maybe you are calling it form Eclipse, since it is using different classpath, and ANT_HOME.

Comment: @Gas any Idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested the following build file on ant 1.7.1 and it works fine.
I'm getting your error, if I remove `wlp-anttasks.jar` from `ant\lib` folder.
So double check, if the file is there and is readable - correct permissions? Maybe you are running build from different user? Or maybe you don't have access to Liberty or server folder?

Check, if the same user can start server from command line using:

```
C:\IBM\WebSphere\wlp\bin>server start WLP_UAT_Server
Starting server WLP_UAT_Server.
Server WLP_UAT_Server started.
```

Here is my `build.xml` file

```
<project name="libertyTest" default="start-server" xmlns:wlp="antlib:com.ibm.websphere.wlp.ant">
    <description>
            description
    </description>
    <!-- set global properties for this build -->
      <property name="wlp_install_dir" value="C:/IBM/WebSphere/wlp"/>
      <property name="serverName" value="WLP_UAT_Server"/>

    <target name="start-server" description="description">
        <wlp:server id="wlp.ant.test" installDir="${wlp_install_dir}" operation="start" serverName="${serverName}" />
        <wlp:server ref="wlp.ant.test" operation="status"/>
    </target>

    <target name="stop-server" description="description">
            <wlp:server id="wlp.ant.test" installDir="${wlp_install_dir}" operation="stop" serverName="${serverName}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Ant properties from diagnostics:

```
-------------------------------------------
 ANT PROPERTIES
-------------------------------------------
ant.version: Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on June 27 2008
ant.java.version: 1.6
ant.core.lib: C:\install\apache-ant-1.7.1\lib\ant.jar
ant.home: C:\install\apache-ant-1.7.1\bin\..
```

Comment: I am still not able to start it from the command line. Its giving me same error which I mentioned in my question and it is perfectly working fine in eclipse.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari Maybe your Ant installation is incorrect. Looking at your ANT Properties they are strange - your `ant.core.lib` is from different folder than your `ant.home`.

Comment: I have installed and on my machine using following command:
"yum install ant". Shall I uninstall it and try something else?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari Yes, uninstall it and just download and unzip installation from http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/

Comment: uninstalling ant and Installing it again does the trick. It worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've missed the step of copying the `wlp-anttasks.jar` into your `$ANT_HOME/lib` directory. Alternatively, if you don't want to alter your ant installation, you can use
the `typedef` task to load the Liberty tasks, for example:

```
<typedef resource="net/wasdev/wlp/ant/antlib.xml" 
       uri="antlib:net.wasdev.wlp.ant" 
       classpath="somewhere/wlp-anttasks.jar"/>
```

Comment: I suspected similar, but if you take a look at his `ANT_HOME/lib` listing, the jar is already there. Unless he is somehow invoking different ant.

Comment: @Holly Cummins...I have copied the wlp-anttasks.jar into $ANT_HOME/lib folder. You can see that under " ANT_HOME/lib jar listing" in the question description.